# I'm stuck in derivatives for finding Curvature of radius I know the formula

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curvature

How can we find the radius of curvature for this equation
$$(x^2+y^2)^2=a^2(x^2-y^2)$$
Here I know the formula but I just want to find y' and y''
I'm stuck in it

here is what know
$$\delta=\frac{(1+y'^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{y''}$$

i got y'
$$y'=\frac{x}{y}\frac{a-2\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)}}{a+2\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)}}$$

Comment: `$\delta=(1+y'^2)^{3/2}/(y'')$` or `$\delta=\frac{(1+y'^2)^{3/2}}{y''}$`      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature#In_2D

Comment: There was a typing mistake in it I just need y' and y''

Comment: Please show us where you got stuck

Comment: i,m stuck after finding y'

Comment: please wait let me show 
$$y'=\frac{x}{y}\frac{a-2sqrt(x^2+y^2)}{a+2sqrt(x^2+y^2)}$$

Comment: @VaibhavDarji Ok please edit your question with this information and the formula you know

Comment: Consider the substitution $\frac yx=t$, t being function of x. This should work because the equation is homogeneous that way.

Comment: you might want to consider expressing this curve in polar form first - i.e. $r^2=a^2\cos{2\theta}$ and then using the polar form for the radius of curvature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier to do this in polar coordinates,

$(x^2+y^2)^2=a^2(x^2-y^2)$

Using $x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta$,

$r^4 = a^2 r^2 \cos2\theta \implies r^2 = a^2 \cos2\theta$

$r_{\theta} = - \cfrac{a^2 \sin2\theta}{r} \implies r_{\theta}^2 = \cfrac{a^4 - r^4}{r^2}$

$r_{\theta \theta} = \cfrac{a^2 \sin2\theta}{r^2} r_{\theta} - \cfrac{2 a^2 \cos2\theta}{r} = - \cfrac{r_{\theta}^2}{r} - 2 r$

Radius of curvature, $R = \cfrac{(r^2 + r_{\theta}^2)^{3/2}}{|r^2 + 2 r_{\theta}^2 - r r_{\theta \theta}| } = \cfrac{\sqrt{r^2 + r_{\theta}^2}}{3}$

$ = \cfrac{a^2}{3 r} = \cfrac{a^2}{3 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$